C# - Com port not working on windows service
I don't have much experience with COM ports, and I'm trying to create a Windows service with the following objectives:
Open all COM port names in a list, for example ("COM1, COM2, COM3, ...").
Open the available COM ports, and display errors for those that could not be opened.
The opened COM ports should be able to read data, as data will be randomly sent to them.
Depending on the COM port that sends data, it will go through a switch to determine its process.
The problem is that when I run the service and use any of the opened COM ports, it only works with that one, and it doesn't work with any other afterwards.
That is, in a hypothetical scenario, if only COM3 and COM4 were opened, both should receive data, but if I use COM3 first, COM4 does not respond and only COM3 remains. How can I solve this problem?
This is my code.

Start service -
  sapEntities db = new sapEntities();

  public Service1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
      try
      {
          WriteToFile($"Call COM port is started at {DateTime.Now}");
          COMDataLog($"Ready at {DateTime.Now}");
          StringCollection stringCollection = Properties.Settings.Default.List_COM;
          string[] ports = new string[stringCollection.Count];
          stringCollection.CopyTo(ports, 0);

          foreach (string portName in ports)
          {
              try
              {
                  SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                  sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
                  sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                  sp.Open();
                  WriteToFile($"{portName} is open at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
              {
                  WriteToFile($"{portName} Error UnauthorizedAccessException: {uae.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              catch (ArgumentException ae)
              {
                  WriteToFile($"{portName} Error ArgumentException: {ae.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                  WriteToFile($"{portName} Error IOException: {ioe.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  WriteToFile($"{portName} Error: {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          WriteToFile($"Error: {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
      }
  }


Receive data  -
  private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {
          SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

          if (sp != null)
          {
              Thread.Sleep(100);
              string data = sp.ReadExisting();
              string cPort = sp.PortName;
              ProcessData(db, cPort, data);
          }
          else
          {
              WriteToFile($"DataReceivedHandler error: SerialPort object is null at {DateTime.Now}");
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          WriteToFile($"DataReceivedHandler error: {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now} ");
      }
  }


Data processing according to the COM port that sends information (There are more COM port options, I just put a few to avoid cluttering the code too much).
  private void ProcessData(sapEntities db, string port, string data)
  {
      var ins_light = new real_light();

      switch (port)
      {
          case "COM1":
              WriteToFile($"COM1 Read: {data} at {DateTime.Now}");
              COMDataLog($"COM1 Read: {data}");

              ins_light = new real_light
              {
                  lgt_date = DateTime.Now,
                  lgt_data = data,
                  lgt_ref = 1
              };

              db.real_light.Add(ins_light);

              try
              {
                  db.SaveChanges();

                  foreach (var entry in b.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                  {
                      entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                  }

                  WriteToFile($"COM1 Data stored correctly: {data} at {DateTime.Now}");

              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  foreach (var entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                  {
                      entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                  }
                  WriteToFile($"COM1 Error data stored {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              break;
          case "COM2":
              WriteToFile($"COM2 Read: {data} at {DateTime.Now}");
              COMDataLog($"COM2 Read: {data}");
              ins_light = new real_light
              {
                  lgt_date = DateTime.Now,
                  lgt_data = data,
                  lgt_ref = 2
              };
              db.real_light.Add(ins_light);

              try
              {
                  db.SaveChanges();
                  foreach (var entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                  {
                      entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                  }
                  WriteToFile($"COM1 Data stored correctly: {data} at {DateTime.Now}");

              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  foreach (var entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                  {
                      entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                  }
                  WriteToFile($"COM1 Error data stored {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
              }
              break;
          default:
              WriteToFile($"Unknown port: {port}");
              break;
      }
  }




I don't have much experience with COM ports: Then you should probably get the code working in either a Windows Forms App or a WPF App first. Once you've achieved that, then you can attempt to get it working as a service. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve (overall) - but your approach seems misguided.

So this isn't good for a service?

In the source code you provided, the serial port object is new in the foreach loop of the OnStart method, but it doesn't seem to be explicitly and permanently saved anywhere. Perhaps because the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is registered, the referrer link source may remain and the object implicitly exists, but isn't there a possibility that it will be discarded by garbage collection?

Searching information about serial port, I forgot to add 2 important things and now works.
1.- Collection serial list
private List<SerialPort> serialPorts = new List<SerialPort>();

2.- Assign to each com port a DataReceived
sp.DataReceived += (sender, e) => DataReceivedHandler(sender, e, portName); 

So, there is the complete edit.
        private List<SerialPort> serialPorts = new List<SerialPort>();
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToFile($"Call COM port is started at {DateTime.Now}");
                COMDataLog($"Ready at {DateTime.Now}");
                StringCollection stringCollection = Properties.Settings.Default.List_COM;
                string[] ports = new string[stringCollection.Count];
                stringCollection.CopyTo(ports, 0);

                foreach (string portName in ports)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                        sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
                        sp.DataReceived += (sender, e) => DataReceivedHandler(sender, e, portName); 
                        sp.Open();
                        serialPorts.Add(sp);
                        WriteToFile($"{portName} is open at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
                    {
                        WriteToFile($"{portName} Error UnauthorizedAccessException: {uae.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException ae)
                    {
                        WriteToFile($"{portName} Error ArgumentException: {ae.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe)
                    {
                        WriteToFile($"{portName} Error IOException: {ioe.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        WriteToFile($"{portName} Error: {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile($"Error: {ex.Message} at {DateTime.Now}");
            }
        }

